# React Js: Is importing urls from a single constants file faster than constructing them in place?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to assign an href prop to a component that will have a url to a page.

```html
<Button
  htmlId="GenerateAANotice"
  buttonStyle="secondary"
  target="_blank"
  href={`${config.BASE_URL}one/${window.dataOne}/two/${window.dataTwo}/three/four/`}
>
  My Button
</Button>
```

Now, as the code above shows that the base URLs have been moved to config as it changes based on the environment. My question is:
Suppose there are two or three places where I need to construct the same URL, then is it ok to construct the same in place as I have in the code shared?
Or will that be a good idea to move the urls to another constants file which would be creating the urls based on the config and then we can directly import the same and use.

Will there be any performance downside to this?

Comment: Optimise when you have performance problems, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tbh. the performance difference is barely noticable, if even noticable, when you compare assigning a value directly vs creating a constant for it if it is does not involve heavy computational operations like API calls, data manipulation/mutation or similar.

But I think for the sake of clean code it definately makes a difference. So reusable constants reduce the number of repetitive code (DRY, Don't repeat yourself)